# Not able to add new record to sqlite database android

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am tring to add new record in my sqlite database. I am not getting any error but also not seen any kind of record in database when i see database using sqlite manager
following is the code which i have written. plz help me to get out of this problem.

following is my code of database handler ..

```
enter code here
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{

private static final int DATABASE_VERSON=1;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME="Info_manager";
private static final String TABLE_DETAILS = "info_detail";

// Contacts Table Columns names
private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
private static final String KEY_FNAME = "f_name";
private static final String KEY_LNAME = "l_name";
private static final String KEY_PH_NO = "c_num";
private static final String KEY_EMAIL = "e_mail";



public DatabaseHandler(Context context) 
{
    super(context,null , null, 1);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) 
{
    //db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ///System.out.println("----333------");
    String CREATE_DETAILS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_DETAILS 
    + "("
    + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + KEY_FNAME + " TEXT," + KEY_LNAME + " TEXT," + KEY_PH_NO + " TEXT," + KEY_EMAIL + " TEXT " + ")";

    db.execSQL(CREATE_DETAILS_TABLE);
    ///System.out.println("----444------");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) 
{
    // Drop older table if existed
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_DETAILS);
    // Create tables again
    onCreate(db);

}


 // Adding new contact
void addContact(Contact contact) 
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
   // ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    String sql;
    sql = "INSERT INTO info_detail (f_name, l_name, c_num, e_mail) " + 
    "VALUES ('" + contact.getfName().toString() + "', '" + contact.getlName().toString() + "', '" + contact.getContactNumber().toString()+ "', '" + contact.getEmailAddress().toString() +"' )";

    db.execSQL(sql);

    /*values.put(KEY_FNAME, contact.getfName());
    values.put(KEY_LNAME, contact.getlName());
    values.put(KEY_PH_NO, contact.getContactNumber());
    values.put(KEY_EMAIL, contact.getEmailAddress());*/
    // Inserting Row
    System.out.print("----inserting----");
    //db.insert(TABLE_DETAILS, null, values);

    System.out.print("----inserted----");
    db.close(); 
}
```

}

and following is the activity from which i called handler

```
public class SQLitelActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener 
{

EditText fname,lname,con_num,email_adr;
Button savebtn,viewbtn;
DatabaseHandler db;
//SQLiteDatabase db;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sqlitel);

    fname=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.fname);
    lname=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.lname);
    con_num=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.cnumber);
    email_adr=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.email);

    savebtn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.save);
    viewbtn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.view);

    db=new DatabaseHandler(this);

    savebtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            //System.out.println("----111------");
            db.addContact(new Contact(fname.getText().toString()
                    , lname.getText().toString(),con_num.getText().toString(),email_adr.getText().toString()));
        //  System.out.println("----222------");
        }
    }
    );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here is code with modification,

```
public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }
```

you miss Database Name here in **super constructor**.

And i am using following METHOD to add contact to database,

```
    // Adding new contact
    void addContact(Contact contact) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_FNAME, contact.getfName().toString()); // Contact First Name
        values.put(KEY_LNAME, contact.getlName().toString()); // Contact Last Name
        values.put(KEY_PH_NO, contact.getContactNumber().toString()); // Contact Number
        values.put(KEY_EMAIL, contact.getEmailAddress().toString() ); // Contact Email

        // Inserting Row
        db.insert(TABLE_CONTACTS, null, values);
        db.close(); // Closing database connection
    }
```

i hope this will help you. Thanks.